# If I remove a developer on gitlab for an iOS project. can they still have access to the code on the local version they downloaded

Tags: gitlab

Basically I had a developer working on my project and he's a crook, and scammer, and im afraid what he might do with my code. SO if I remove him from the gitlab member, does he still have access to the code of the branch in Xcode on the version he downloaded.

Comment: Yes, of course; that's on their local machine

Comment: so am I screwed

Comment: what If they take the code, finish the project and release the app themselves

Comment: We can't address what might or might not happen with that developer here. Contact an attorney if you don't have a contract in place to protect your intellectual property.